# Приведение типов. Почему это так работает?

Tags: java, c#, ооп, теория

Сейчас речь про C#, но я думаю, что это так работает и в других языках программирования.

```
class A: object
class B: A
```

Теперь получается, что можно сделать вот так

```
A a = new B();
```

А вот так сделать нельзя

```
B b = new A();
```

Но почему?
Когда мы делаем вот так

```
new B();
```

В памяти выделяется место под все методы и поля, которые есть в классе B. А потом это кладется в переменную типа A, в которой не все эти методы и поля есть. Получается мы должны терять часть полей и методов, но нет. Почему?
Всё буквально кричит о том, что в переменную типа B должно быть можно присваивать тип A. Потому что у типа В есть всё то же что и у типа А, но и ещё даже больше.
Это как с переменной типа int 64 и int 32. Значение из типа int 32 можно поместить в переменную int 64, потому что оно поместится. А наоборот - нет. Тут же аналогичная история, но всё работает абсолютно не так. Почему?

Comment: _В памяти выделяется место под все методы и поля, которые есть в классе B_ - но в классе А может не быть полей, которые нужны классу B ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ - именно поэтому просто так и нельзя присвоить базовый класс потомку

Comment: Ну наоборот же, должно быть нельзя в переменную базового класса присваивать объект класса-потомка? Класс-потомок наследует всё, что есть у базового класса, но там могут быть добавлены ещё и другие поля или методы. А потом мы вот это всё добавляем в переменную базового класса, а он же не должен даже знать о тех полях, которые были добавлены после наследования?

Comment: А он и не знает ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ да и обратиться ты можешь только к тому что есть в A, а значит точно есть в B. В обратном случае такое уже не работает

Comment: Я думал, что можно. Тогда всё, конечно, намного логичнее.
А получается, что можно создать объект типа В, там есть какое-то поле, туда положить значение. Потом создать переменную типа object, привести значение из первой переменной к типу object, потом привести обратно к типу В, положить в переменную типа В и значение, которое было положено в поле останется? То есть при преобразовании к базовому классу поля и методы становятся недоступными, но не удалятся. И если обратно привести к изначальному типу то всё разблокируется и значения там останутся?

Comment: Да, фактически ничего никуда не кладется и тип у объекта всегда один и тот же остается.